# use -source 7 or higher

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While trying to build a project using intelliJ Ultimate 12 I am getting these errors

```
use -source or higher to enable diamond operator
use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement
```

I used the same code with same intelliJ Ultimate 12 on some other system and its working fine there. I want to know what configurations I need to set in my IDE to fix these build issues?

Comment: in project structure --> project --> project language level, is it set to java 7 correctly?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

the language level for a project is set in the project structure dialog:
[image: project structure dialog]
you want to make sure you set the language level to java 7, and the sdk accordingly

Comment: Don't forget a "Rebuild application" to clean.

Comment: if you see that intellij language level is already set to the correct one -- you might downgrade it and upgrade it again for that to take effect. I had to do this for Intellij 15 after I freshly imported my gradle project.

Answer (score 34):

In addition to the accepted answer, you may also need to change the language level under Project Structure > Modules > Sources tab.

I also needed to change the java compiler being used at the IDE level under IntelliJ IDEA > Preference > Compiler > Java Compiler to 1.7 from 1.6. The exact location of the setting will vary based on your OS and version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: THANK YOU, there's so many answers to these kinds of questions that don't mention the compiler

Answer (score 12):

For me, it's because the `maven-compiler-plugin`'s `source` and `target` is set to 1.6 rather than 1.7 in `pom.xml`, changing it to 1.7 solved the problem.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and was struggling. Auto-import was true, re-import of project was not working and tried all possible options. But finally i found the solution. 
**"Reimport All Maven Projects"** did the trick for me. 
You can find the option on the Maven Project tab.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me.

I had to explicitly add the following plugin statement to my pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

(Well, IDEA made it for me when I clicked the red help lamp and selected "Set project Java level to 7", so maybe try that if this also doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

If using Gradle as a build automation, set following settings in build.gradle and re-import your project:

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

targetCompatibility = 1.7

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.2:

- In the project tool window, right-click on the project name to get to the Project Structure menu.
- Set *Language Level* to whatever version you want, and rebuild project again.

You can also use **F4** as shortcut to get to the same menu.