# Map values to ArrayList

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have a `Map<Integer, MyClass>` and `MyClass` has 2 fields, `Object1 obj` and `Object2 objj` for example.

How can I create an `ArrayList<Object2>` with all `Object2` values?

Must I iterate the `Map` and then add the values to the `ArrayList` or exists another way?

Comment: If you only want `ArrayList<Object2>` and not `ArrayList<MyClass>`, then you have to iterate and check `instanceof Object2` to get those classes.

Comment: Object2 is a field, not an extending class

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Java 8 you could do:

```
List<Object2> list = map.values()
                        .stream()
                        .map(v -> v.objj)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are using Java 7 or earlier, the [solution of @Marv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043588/3798217) is the simplest.

Comment: @HugoSilva Yes, that's Java 8. I'm not sure why that doesn't work. I don't think I've made a typo, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki Thanks for that. I guess the OP needs to google the error message.

Comment: done! ty guys! I had just to change Project language Level in Project Properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659554/use-source-7-or-higher

Answer (score 10):

You could iterate over the values of the `Map`:

```
ArrayList<Object2> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (MyClass e : map.values()) {
    list.add(e.objj);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Checkout following :

[How do I convert a Map to List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

It has one liner snippet for your question.

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(map.values());
```

assuming:

```
Map<Integer, MyClass> map;
```

Comment: Not exactly, as map.values() will give you Collection<MyClass> instead of Object2