# Meteor Cordova plugin fails at building : use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator

Tags: java, android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have developed a plugin for Cordova. All was fine with my environment development. Now I try to use it in a fresh Meteor Cordova project and I have this errors popping up.
How to fix this ? I don't have any IDE for java to [fix this like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659554/use-source-7-or-higher) in a Cordova project.

```
While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/vikti/dev/cordova-mapbox-test/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --emulator
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

   /Users/vikti/dev/cordova-mapbox-test/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/telerik/plugins/mapbox/CDVMapbox.java:523:
   error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
   ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
   ^
   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

   /Users/vikti/dev/cordova-mapbox-test/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/telerik/plugins/mapbox/MapController.java:84:
   error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
   private ArrayList<String> _offlineRegionsNames = new
   ArrayList<>();
   ^
   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

   /Users/vikti/dev/cordova-mapbox-test/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/telerik/plugins/mapbox/MapController.java:498:
   error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
   } catch (SVGParseException | IOException e) {
   ^
   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)

   /Users/vikti/dev/cordova-mapbox-test/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/telerik/plugins/mapbox/MapsManager.java:22:
   error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
   private static SparseArray<Map> _maps = new
   SparseArray<>();
   ^
```

Comment: this answer resolved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386152/override-java-version-when-building-a-cordova-project-with-gradle